# ios music player app with Equalizer Settings

Tags: ios, iphone, equalizer

I have a requirement of developing a music app on **Iphone**. I have achieved other modules but i am stuck at one thing that is **Equalizer**. I want list of all available equalizer in the phone and can apply it to my playing songs.

I have no idea what to do or which direction i have to go.

Kindly help.

Comment: HI @Paras Did you find an answer for this,If so please share it with us :)